# Detect if window.location.assign() has received a response

Tags: javascript

I'm using `window.location.assign()` method for downloading a file. The backend API returns a streaming response. So the user remains on the same page and download gets started.

Now the thing is, I want to call another API as soon as I receive a response for my download request. But I'm not sure how to do that. Can some one tell me, how to detect that `window.location.assign()` has received a response?

Comment: There's no mechanism for that that I'm aware of.